# How could I use the access token provided from Passport JS later on?

Tags: reactjs, express, passport.js

I am experimenting with Spotify API, and I am using Node JS, Express, React, Passport JS. I authenticate with passport JS, and within the setup, there is a parameter that is the access token. With this access token, I can access a user's library and other information. But I am not sure how to access this access token afterwards. I mean, I want to use it when the user clicks on certain button, not when the user logs in. How can I "save" this access token or access it later?

I have tried returning the access token after the "done(err,user)" but I don't know where it is being returned to.

this is my passport setup:

```
passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.spotify.clientID,
      clientSecret: keys.spotify.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: "/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate({
        where: {
          user_spotify_id: profile.id,
          username: profile.username,
          email: profile._json.email,
          country: profile.country,
          birthdate: profile._json.birthdate
        }
      }).then(([user, created]) => {

        done(null, user);
        // return accessToken;
      });
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try one of these options.

1. Have a column in the User table / model that is called "spotifyAccessToken" and store it there.
2. Or have a separate table that stores access tokens with a foreign key to the user table.

When the user logs out, destroy the token.

```
passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.spotify.clientID,
      clientSecret: keys.spotify.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: "/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate({
        where: {
          user_spotify_id: profile.id,
          username: profile.username,
          email: profile._json.email,
          country: profile.country,
          birthdate: profile._json.birthdate
        }
      }).then(([user, created]) => {

        // store access token
        User.update({
          spotifyAccessToken: accessToken
        }, {
          where: {
            id: user.id
          },
          returning: true // returns the user after update
        }).then(result => {
          user = result[1][0]; // get user

          done(null, user);
        });
      });
    }
  )
);
```